# resource path setting java jar

Tags: java, jar, path, resources

I have a folder and package structure looking like this

- XXX

  - src

    - view(classes in here)
  - rsrc

    - view(images in here)

The class files, are using images of the image folders. While building a jar i dont have a problem with inserting images, i just copy (in my build.xml) the rsrc folder content to the src folder build, so the resources are in the .class path:

```
<copydir src="./rsrc/studentapp/view/"
   dest="${build}/studentapp/view/"/>
```

After creating my jar I can get resources by (example):

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("testimage.png");
```

The problem is, if i just want to compile a class without creating a jar, the above line wont work because it's not in the right folder. Is there a way to read out a file relatively back this order structure and also have it to work in the jar too?

best regards

EDIT: Working with windows maybe there is a different syntax

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by just setting path relative to rscrc and  copy the whole rsrc folder to the jar build

```
String path = "rsrc\\studentapp\\view\\testimage.png";
    File test = new File(path);
    try {
           BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(test);

           ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
              " <- Image should appear here", "Testimage",
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here the line in the build.xml:

```
  <copydir src="./rsrc" dest="${build}"/>
```